# Unable to return function value from custom command

Tags: cypress

I am having a hard time returning a value from a custom command function to the main file.

**command.js**

[image]

**spec.js**

[image]

it does not return the expected value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to return the `decodedTotp` value?
If yes, you have to do this explicitly at the end of your custom function:

```js
<...>
    console.log(decodedTotp)
    return decodedTotp
  })
})
```

Comment: what do you mean by explicitly?

Comment: I mean the return statement: `return decodedTotp`

Comment: Still returns undefined

Comment: what your console log shows? does `decodedTotp` have any value? and what does `Decoder.scan` function do? does it return a cypress chain?

Comment: the variable should return a generated OTP from the QR code with google authentication, and the Decoder.scan scans the src attributte of a qr code image. it does not return a cypress chain

Comment: so Decoder.scan does not return a cypress chain and it has **its own** `then` function?
could you provide its source code?

Comment: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/4929#issuecomment-569302392

Comment: okay, I got it: the `scan` function returns a promise so you have to add an additional `return` statement here: http://prntscr.com/26ce42u